# Flyway-Jenkins Integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build-automation, flyway

I recently started using Flyway command line and its perfect. Now I want to integrate flyway with Jenkins. I was able to install flyway-runner plugin without any issues.

But, now I am stuck at flyway installation for Jenkins. I copied over the flyway folder to Jenkins installation folder; for e.g. `C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/flyway-4.2.0`, and that is the path I defined in 'Global Tools Configuration' in Jenkins. But I am getting below error when trying to build with Jenkins:

```
Building in workspace C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/db_deploy

FATAL: Flyway installation was not found
ERROR: Build step 'Invoke Flyway' failed due to errors
Finished: Failure
```

Comment: Can you provide me the screenshot of Global Configuration and Build Step Details.

Comment: Never mind. I got it to work by playing around. Thanks Suresh!

Comment: I think you didn't provided full path of the flyway tool. It has to be full path along with flyway.cmd

Comment: Hi Suresh, is there a way to have 1 flyway installation and use it in multiple builds with different flyway parameters? For e.g. I have three different projects with thier respective version_history table. I want to have 3 builds and want to pass in flyway.table=projectTable parameter. I tried flywayrunner DSL job with 6th extra parameter table=projectTable. But it looks like it can only except 5 parameters i.e. name,command,url,location,credentialsid.  Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: There is one more argument that you can pass Command line arguments as commandLineArgs('Key=Value').

Comment: Suresh - I am getting: ERROR: No signature of method: script.flywayRunner () is applicable for argument types: (script$_run_closure1)

Comment: Can I get the full script.

Comment: Here it is. Also, can cammandLineArgs jave more than 1 argument? This is what I am doing: flywayRunner {name ('flyway') command ('info') url ('myDBUrl') locations ('filesystem:$WORKSPACE/main') credentialsId ('xxx there is actual value xxx') commandLineArgs ('table=myTable')}

Comment: If you are using Flyway step in Jenkins Pipeline job, the syntax is different flywayrunner commandLineArgs: '-table=myTable', credentialsId: 'xxx there is actual value xxx', flywayCommand: 'info', installationName: 'Flyway', locations: 'filesystem:$WORKSPACE/main', url: 'jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver:3306/mydb'

Comment: I am using Process Job DSLs

Comment: freeStyleJob('FlywayDSLTest') {  
 steps {
   flywayRunner {
            name('flyway')
            command('info')
            url('jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver:3306/mydb')
            commandLineArgs('-skipDefaultResolvers=true')
        }
 }
} I tried with this it was able to create the build step in the respective Job through DSL